# C++ функции и строки

Tags: char, строки, c++

Хочу написать функцию которая будет удалять символ после определённого символа

```
void deleteChar(char symbol, char *str){
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str) - 1; i++){
        if(str[i] == symbol){
            for(int j = i; j < strlen(str) - 1; j++) str[j] = str[j + 1];
        }
    }
}
```

И потом в main() :

```
 if(symbol == 'o') deleteChar('o', str);
```

Но не работает как мне надо, точнее вообще не работает, где я неправ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ад, используйте memset.

```
void deleteChar(char symbol, char *str){
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str) - 1; i++){
        if(str[i] == symbol){
           memset(str+i,0,strlen(str)-i);
           return;
        }
    }
}
```

Кстати сам поиск первой встречи символа можно организовать без цикла с помощью библиотечной функции strchr, что сократит ваш код до двух строчек.

```
i = strchr (str,'а') - str;  //Ищем первое включение "а" в *str.
memset(str+i,0,strlen(str)-i); //Удаляем все
```

Можно пойти дальше, еще немного оптимизировать и получить однострочник.

```
memset(strchr (str,'а'),0, str+strlen(str) - strchr (str,'а'));
```

Не знаю работает ли он, но вроде внешне все правильно. Для юникода скорее всего не будет работать, так как используется арифметика указателей.

Однострочник удаляющий только один символ(тут 3 раза считается strchr, можно ввести переменную буфер, чтобы ускорить процесс):

```
memmove(strchr (str,'а'),strchr (str,'а')+1, str+strlen(str) - strchr (str,'а')-1);
```

P.S. Если кто-то будет этим пользоваться сообщите о результате/дебаге в тред.

Comment: Так мне не надо все удалять, только следующий

Comment: тогда вместо memset, нужно memmove сдвинуть правую часть строки на один символ влево.